# How to convert a decimal number to ASCII representation

Tags: number-formats

The question that was in my lecture notes said

```
    "Encode the decimal number 2370  in ASCII. "
```

and the answer given there is

```
    32 33 37 30 (ASCII code representation)
```

My question is how do we get this? Do we simply add 30 to each digit? I am sorry if this is a very obvious question I do not know the correct way to look up the ASCII table for conversions. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: This is not my homework, my course finished today morning. Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Look up the symbol table on Wikipedia. What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASCII encodings for digits 0 to 9 are 48 to 57 in decimal, or 30 to 39 in hexadecimal.